# how to represent a binomial coefficient in terms of a series?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I have to find the power series for (n+m C m) or (n+m C m ) - 1 i.e representing it in some sort of power . Is it even possible ? 
P.S. :- Thanks in advance .

Comment: Are you certain you need a power series for the binomial coefficient and not rather a generating function, which as a power series will contain those as coefficients?